# swift - create a page for both repeated data and for no data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I need an advice with ViewContoller's scheme. I should create a view with Billing addresses. There can be no address at all, or some addresses. If there no one, there should be only a button "Add New". And if there are addresses, each should have buttons Edit, Remove, and "Add New" too.

I have data for this VC as JSON, parsed and saved to plist.

So what is logic to make this View looks different depends on 1) if there are addresses or not? and 2) if there 1, or 2, or maybe 20 billing addresses?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add a button programmatically and assign it to your tableview background view.

Comment: You can place `add button` in navigation bar (so, it will always be visible)
And place addresses in UITableView as cells with buttons

Comment: Do you have any design concept?

Comment: Sounds like a tableview would be able to do what you want

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean like make initial View with empty cell, and then fill and add another one if needed according to data , using code? yes I guess it will work fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved issues like this with UITableVIew and the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate:

1. setup the table view for one section (adresses)

   ```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {return 1;}
   ```
2. return the address arrays length in the delegate method

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     return adresses.count
    }
   ```
3. set the view for footer if the arrays length is 0

   ```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       if adresses.count == 0  {
           let vw = YourViewClass()
           //I use blockskit library here (vw.bk_) to recognize a tap, but you can add a button by yourself
           vw.bk_(whenTapped: {
              //Create and present your next viewcontroller to 
           })
           return vw
       }
       return nil
       }
   ```
4. set the footers height to 0 if there are addresses

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

       if addresses.count > 0 {
           return YOUR_DESIRED_FOOTER_HEIGHT_FOR_INPUT
       }
       return 0
   }
   ```
5. create row for each address

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
      let address = addresses[indexPath.row]
      let tableViewCell = UITableViewCell() //maybe you have to create your own if the layout does not fit
      //set tableViewCell's title / description to show address values
      return tableViewCell
   }
   ```

In this case, the footer view (you can do the same in the header if you want) with the add button is shown when no addresses are available, and it is hidden, when addresses are available.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! and if each row should contain address itself and 2 buttons, I need to make a reusable cell, right? Oh so stupid questions, but I'm just learning =)

Comment: yes, you can subclass the UITableViewCell and add any UIView like an UIButton as you wish if the original layout does not fit. If you need to adjust the row height there is another delegate method you have to override and then just return the value you need